# How to read response data in an Undertow HttpServerExchange object?

Tags: java, reverse-proxy, undertow

I have implemented a reverse proxy with `Undertow` server.

I want to edit the absolute URLs in the response from target host before sending back to client.

I've used `exchange.addResponseCommitListener(httpHandler)` so that exchange object contains response from the proxied server and the response hasn't been sent to the client yet.

In `httpHandler`, I'm able to see the exact length of the proxied response with `exchange.getResponseContentLength()` but unable to find any function that reads the response data.

I've checked the implementation of `exchange.getResponseContentLength()` but its only giving the value from one of response headers `Content-Length`.

Can anyone please help me how to retrieve the response data that has been proxied. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to use addResponseWrapper. ResponseCommitListener is invoked just before the response is committed, so there's no response body sent yet.

Comment: @vbezhenar In the ResponseCommitListener I'm able to get the exact size of the response with exchange.getResponseContentLength() so I'm thinking response data should be present at that point.